# Set a default value for a lookup field

Tags: lookup, default-value

I would like to find a way to create an opportunity and set a default value for the field "Primary Campaign Source", the value will be all the time the same.

It will be possible for the user to change the value when he creates the opportunity.

Do you have an idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using a Flow.

Winter '20 added a [Record Lookup](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter20/release-notes/rn_forcecom_flow_fbuilder_lookup.htm) feature that allows you to pre-populate a lookup value by setting the `Record Id` field value on the lookup component. (Seen on the right in the image below)

[image: lookup component in lightning flow builder]

Comment: Is it possible to display the flow dependent of the profile?